# Why doesn't logstash produce logs?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, devops, logstash-grok

i read below articles to understand logstash technology i established ELK environment. 
https://tpodolak.com/blog/tag/kibana/

```
input {
    file {
        path => ["C:/logs/*.log"]
        start_position => beginning
        ignore_older => 0

    }
}
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "TimeStamp=%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate} CorrelationId=%{UUID:correlationId} Level=%{LOGLEVEL:logLevel} Message=%{GREEDYDATA:logMessage}" }
    }
    # set the event timestamp from the log
    # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html
    date {
         match => [ "logdate", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS" ]
        target => "@timestamp"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

i added input path C/logs/*.log in logstash.conf. i have test.log file that is not empty, it has :

```
TimeStamp=2016-07-20 21:22:46.0079 CorrelationId=dc665fe7-9734-456a-92ba-3e1b522f5fd4 Level=INFO Message=About
TimeStamp=2016-07-20 21:22:46.0079 CorrelationId=dc665fe7-9734-456a-92ba-3e1b522f5fd4 Level=INFO Message=About
TimeStamp=2016-11-01 00:13:01.1669 CorrelationId=77530786-8e6b-45c2-bbc1-31837d911c14 Level=INFO Message=Request completed with status code: 200
```

According to above article. i have to see that my logs inside of the elasticsearch. 
(From "https://tpodolak.com/blog/tag/kibana/" sample result )
[image]
But my result if i write to my browser this adress: http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v  i can not see logstash logs in elasticsearch? where is logstash logs stored in elastic search? logstash.conf looks ok. but there is no satisfied result. As a result. i want to get all logs from under C/logs/*.log TO elastic by logstash? but what is my error in my logstash.conf?
[image]

My LOGS (C:\monitoring\logstash\logs\C:\monitoring\logstash\logs.log):

```
[2017-03-13T10:47:17,849][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Using config.test_and_exit mode. Config Validation Result: OK. Exiting Logstash
[2017-03-13T11:46:35,123][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Using config.test_and_exit mode. Config Validation Result: OK. Exiting Logstash
[2017-03-13T11:48:20,023][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Using config.test_and_exit mode. Config Validation Result: OK. Exiting Logstash
[2017-03-13T11:55:10,808][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500}
[2017-03-13T11:55:10,871][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline main started
[2017-03-13T11:55:11,316][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2017-03-13T12:00:52,188][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Using config.test_and_exit mode. Config Validation Result: OK. Exiting Logstash
[2017-03-13T12:02:48,309][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Using config.test_and_exit mode. Config Validation Result: OK. Exiting Logstash
[2017-03-13T12:06:33,270][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Cannot load an invalid configuration {:reason=>"Expected one of #, => at line 1, column 52 (byte 52) after output { elasticsearch { hosts "}
[2017-03-13T12:08:51,636][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Cannot load an invalid configuration {:reason=>"Expected one of #, => at line 1, column 22 (byte 22) after input {  file { path "}
[2017-03-13T12:09:48,114][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Cannot load an invalid configuration {:reason=>"Expected one of #, => at line 1, column 22 (byte 22) after input {  file { path "}
[2017-03-13T12:11:40,200][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Cannot load an invalid configuration {:reason=>"Expected one of #, => at line 1, column 22 (byte 22) after input {  file { path "}
[2017-03-13T12:19:17,622][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Using config.test_and_exit mode. Config Validation Result: OK. Exiting Logstash
```

Comment: What is the logstash output?

Comment: @asettouf; my logstash out but is :   output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
    }
    stdout {}
}

Comment: Sorry I meant the output on the console or in the logs of logstash

Comment: How can i see my logs on the console?  http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v

Comment: My log file has : TimeStamp=2016-07-20 21:22:46.0079 CorrelationId=dc665fe7-9734-456a-92ba-3e1b522f5fd4 Level=INFO Message=About
TimeStamp=2016-07-20 21:22:46.0079 CorrelationId=dc665fe7-9734-456a-92ba-3e1b522f5fd4 Level=INFO Message=About
TimeStamp=2016-11-01 00:13:01.1669 CorrelationId=77530786-8e6b-45c2-bbc1-31837d911c14 Level=INFO Message=Request completed with status code: 200

Comment: When you start logstash, it will write things on the console, same for elasticsearch, it might be interesting to see what's there

Comment: i added my logs in logstash. PLease check it . i need your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you have a few configuration issues:

- Hosts in Elasticsearch should be an array (e.g `hosts => ["myHost:myPort3]`), see [the doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-hosts)
- File on Windows using the wildcard should use forward slashes and not backward (see [this issue](https://github.com/cityindex-attic/logsearch/issues/100))
- Your date filter is looking for a field "logdate" when it should look for the field "TimeStamp" (given your log file)
- One setting I would had for convenience is the `sincedb_path` as Logstash will not try to parse again a file it already parsed (it checks into a .sincedb to see if it already parsed a file, by default located at $HOME/.sincedb, **you need to delete it in between parsing when you test with the same log file**)

That's why after a few research (actually a lot, not being a windows user), I could come up with this config that works:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:/some/log/dir/*"
        start_position => beginning
        ignore_older => 0
        sincedb_path => "NIL" #easier to remove from the current directory, the file will be NIL.sincedb

    }
}
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "TimeStamp=%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate} CorrelationId=%{UUID:correlationId} Level=%{LOGLEVEL:logLevel} Message=%{GREEDYDATA:logMessage}" }
    }
    # set the event timestamp from the log
    # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html
    date {
         match => [ "TimeStamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" ]
        target => "@timestamp"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

Comment: I don't have $HOME in my environment

Comment: The equivalent for windows, probably %HOMEPATH% (which should be by default C:\Users\MyUserName\)